# How to save data from spark streaming to cassandra using java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I get some entries from the stream in linux terminal, assign them as `lines`, break them into `words`. But instead of printing them out I want to save them to Cassandra.
I have a Keyspace named `ks`, with a table inside it named `record`.
I know that some code like `CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(words).writerBuilder("ks", "record").saveToCassandra();` has to do the job but I guess I am doing something wrong. Can someone help ?

Here is my Cassandra ks.record schema (I added these data through CQLSH)

```
id | birth_date                       | name
----+---------------------------------+-----------
10 | 1987-12-01 23:00:00.000000+0000  | Catherine
11 | 2004-09-07 22:00:00.000000+0000  |   Isadora
1  | 2016-05-10 13:00:04.452000+0000  |      John
2  | 2016-05-10 13:00:04.452000+0000  |      Troy
12 | 1970-10-01 23:00:00.000000+0000  |      Anna
3  | 2016-05-10 13:00:04.452000+0000  |    Andrew
```

Here is my Java code :

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.*;


public class CassandraStreaming2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CassandraStreaming");
        JavaStreamingContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));

        // Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = sc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

        // Split each line into words
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(
                (FlatMapFunction<String, String>) x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" "))
        );

        words.print();
        //CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(words).writerBuilder("ks", "record").saveToCassandra();

        sc.start();              // Start the computation
        sc.awaitTermination();   // Wait for the computation to terminate

    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error `Error:(38, 60) java: method writerBuilder in class com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory<java.lang.String>
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

for the line `CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(words).writerBuilder("ks", "record").saveToCassandra();
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md#saving-data-to-cassandra

As per the docs, you need to also pass a RowWriter factory. The most common way to do this is to use the  `mapToRow(Class)` api, this is the missing parameter described.

But you have an additional problem, your code doesn't yet specify the data in a way that can be written to C*. You have a JavaDStream of only `String`s. And a single `String` cannot be made into a Cassandra Row for your given schema.

Basically you are telling the connector

`Write "hello" to CassandraTable (id, birthday, value)`

Without telling it where the `hello` goes (what should the id be? what should the birthday be?)

Comment: I couldn't solve the "additional problem" you mentioned. Would you please explain how should I accomplish that ?

Comment: You are missing required fields. You need to provide them. In C* you always must at least specify the primary key. This means the objects you are writing to C* must have a value for "id" and "birthday". This could mean you write `Tuple3(id, timestamp, string)` or make a custom class with fields like `RowClass( Integer id; Timestamp birthday, String Value; Integer getId() ... `

Comment: You are correct. After I solved what you mentioned, the piece of code that helped it worked was to change `JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(
                (FlatMapFunction<String, String>) x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" "))
        );` into `JavaDStream<Word> words = lines.flatMap(
                (FlatMapFunction<String, String>) x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" "))
        ).map(s -> new Word(s));` . 
Word class was a class for mapping the cassandra tables to what I am getting from the terminal